# How can I remove Unwanted edge pixals in images in android using scale types?

Tags: android

I have an Image Which has unwanted Edge pixels,I need to remove them to get the round corners of that image,so which scale type I need to use on that image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Make one xml file to res/drawable folder and paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#7daa0d" />
    <solid android:color="#1e1e1e" />   
   <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Here give radius value to this as much round edges. i.e `<corners android:radius="120dp" />`